# can I prevent firebug lite div from stacking on top of the glimpse div?

Tags: glimpse, firebug-lite

[Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) displays a div tag in the bottom right of the window when included on a page. The new tool [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com) uses the same method to display a div for it's activation as well. My problem is that the glimpse div appears under the firebug div in z-order.

Is there a simple clever way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change Firebug Lite options to not display that little icon:

https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js#showIconWhenHidden=false

There are different ways to set options. Read more here:

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Options

Comment: the options were exactly what I was looking for. thanks for pionting out the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a little JavaScript on your page that grabs either the Glimpse or FireBug Light div (if present) and changes the placement or zIndex.